# binary masks in CAPL

Tags: capl

CAPL allows bitwise operations. Since writing parsers is becoming a tedious operation these days, I'm wandering if there is a way to write binary numbers for masks, e.g.

```
variables
{
    byte a = 0x03;
}

on key 'a'
{
    a &= 0b11;  // <- invalid, how can we write this?
    a &= 0x03;
    a &= 3;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not supported by CAPL.
You just have to add the bits and use the obtained number in Hex or Dec format.
Alternatively you can create a function to display it in your report as a binary if you really want to